# Finding roots of the equation $8x^3+4x^2-4x-1=0$ which are in form of cosine of angles.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

So, I start this by reducing it to a cubic with 0 coefficient of the 2nd degree term which gives me :
$$\left(x + \frac{1}{6}\right)^3 - \frac{7}{12}\left(x + \frac{1}{6}\right)-\frac{7}{216}=0$$

Replacing $\left(x + \frac{1}{6}\right)$ by $y$:
$$y^3-\frac{7}{12}y -\frac{7}{216}=0$$

Then replacing $y$ by $r \cos(\alpha)$ and comparing the equation with :
$$\cos^3 (\alpha) - \frac{3}{4}\cos(\alpha)-\frac{1}{4}\cos(3\alpha)=0$$

I get:
$$r = \sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}, \alpha = \frac{1}{3}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\right)$$

which finally give:
$$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{9}\cos^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\right)-\frac{1}{6}\right)$$
which is approximately 1.329 on putting it in the calculator.

But if I consider the common problem:
$8x^3-4x^2-4x+1=0$ having roots $\cos(\pi/7), \cos(3\pi/7), \cos(5\pi/7)$.

If I replace $x$ by $-x$ in this equation, we get:
$$8x^3+4x^2-4x-1=0$$
which is same the expression in the actual problem. So its roots must be $-\cos(\pi/7), -\cos(3\pi/7), -\cos(5\pi/7)$. This clearly doesn't matches with the answer I got.

Where I go wrong? Also can someone confirm while comparing coefficients in $cos(\alpha)$ variable cubic equation, we treat $\cos(3\alpha)$ as a constant. My book give a special section in which it shows this method of comparing in this way. So I guess its probably right? But I am not sure how is it right, isn't $\cos(3\alpha)$ also dependent on the main variable $\cos(\alpha)$.

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: First, the exponential of leading $y$ is three, not two. I believe this is a typo. (I'm still looking at this proof.)

Comment: Also, could you elaborate more on how to get your $r,\alpha,\theta$? Because to my experience, it is really rare to have to arccosine there.

Comment: @BenjaminWang I assumed $y$ to be $r \cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle for which it satisifies the equation which I have later found too.

Comment: @JetfiRex Yup, thanks for pointing out the typo.
So for finding $r, \alpha$  I changed the equation in y to be a cubic in $\cos(\alpha)$ by putting $r cos(\alpha)$ and then I compared coefficients with the triple angle formula in cos. There's where a doubt arises, it doing that correct as $cos(3\alpha)$ is also in form of the variable. But my book have done it, so I too took the same way. Comparing directly gives $r,\alpha$ and then $y$ could be found, hence $\theta$ can be found from $x$.

Comment: Finally, I try to trust your result by taking $y=r\cos(\alpha)$ with your solved $r,\alpha$ into equation $y^3-7/12y-7/216=0$, but it does not hold.

Comment: But all in all your book does not find a correct $r$ and $\alpha$... You could plug in the things yourself to check. Could you calculate it again and then find the correct ones?

Comment: I am also pretty sure answer is wrong, but not able to find a bold mistake, except I am not sure about the $\cos(3\alpha)$ thing. I have added references from book here: https://imgur.com/a/jdVABQB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134949/discussion-between-jetfirex-and-aayush).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we take $t=2x$   we have $t^3 + t^2 - 2t - 1$

next, take complex number $w$   with $w \neq 1$  but $w^7 = 1.$   Factoring out a $w-1$ tells us $1 + w + w^2 + w^3 + w^4 + w^5 + w^6 = 0.$   Now take $t = w + w^6$  which is the same as $w + \frac{1}{w}.$   We find $ t^2 = w^2 + 2 + w^5,$   while $t^3 = w^3 + 3 w + \frac{3}{w}  + \frac{1}{w^3} = w^3 + 3 w + 3 w^6 + w^4 $

Adding,
$$  t^3 + t^2 =    w^3 + 3 w + 3 w^6 + w^4  +  w^2 + 2 + w^5  ,$$
in order
$$ t^3 + t^2 = 3 w^6 + w^5 + w^4 + w^3 + w^2 + 3w + 2$$   so that
$$ t^3 + t^2 -2t =  w^6 + w^5 + w^4 + w^3 + w^2 + w + 2$$   and
$$ t^3 + t^2 -2t - 1 =  w^6 + w^5 + w^4 + w^3 + w^2 + w + 1$$

finally
$$ t^3 + t^2 -2t - 1 =  0$$

Taking $w = \cos \frac{2\pi}{7}  + i \sin \frac{2\pi}{7},$   so that
$ 1/w =  \cos \frac{2\pi}{7}  - i \sin \frac{2\pi}{7},$  we see
$$    t = 2\cos \frac{2\pi}{7} $$

is one of the roots $t.$   Next we may take $w = \cos \frac{4\pi}{7}  + i \sin \frac{4\pi}{7},$  so that  $    t = 2\cos \frac{4\pi}{7} $  is another root. The last one can be $w = \cos \frac{8\pi}{7}  + i \sin \frac{8\pi}{7},$so that  $    t = 2\cos \frac{8\pi}{7} $  is the third root.

Answer (score 1):

From the book in the chat, we can spot that the wrong thing is $r$, it should be $\sqrt{7}/3$ not $\sqrt{7/3}$.

So, your $\theta$ should be (I think you have a wrong calculation there!)

$$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{7}}{{\color{red} 3}}{\color{red}\cos}\left( {\color{red}{\frac13}} \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{7}}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{6}\right)$$

Which is actually $2\pi/7$, fit $-\cos(5\pi/7)$ root.

As for equation $$\cos^3\theta+\frac{3H}{r^2}\cos\theta+\frac{G}{r^3}=0$$

We notice that there are some spaces to solve $\theta$ by adjusting $r$. Notice that no matter how we adjust, the linear term can't be cancelled, but we need a way to make the equation to solve easily. The triple-angle formula for cosine has nonzero linear term. That is why we put $3H/r^2=-3/4$ (and hence $G/r^3=-\cos(3\theta)/4$) since we can use the triple-angle formula there to solve.

Comment: Oh right, Thank you so much !
Also is there way to actually find that it is $-5\pi/7$ without calculator as In actual question, it was mentioned in form of $\frac{-\pi}{n+1}$ where $n$ is integer.

Comment: Also can you explain why that comparing part is right? Like equating cos^3 (\alpha) to the constant term where we are taking $\cos (\alpha) $ only as the variable.

Comment: @Aayush You mean the part like $3H/r^2=3/4$ and $G/r^3=-\cos(3\theta)/4$, why we can do like that...? Sure, I try to figure it out and add it into the post.

Comment: I am sure that 3H/r^2 one could be done, but $cos(3\theta)$ one kinda is the one which is confusing me.

Comment: @Aayush I think it is kind of natural to do this...? Since the equation (2) has two variables, one could add one more constraint to make it easier to solve... Like, the cubic intersect a line will always have a solution so basically we put $r$ as $3H/r^2=3/4$, and therefore we can calculate that $G/r^3=-\cos(3\theta)/4$... Basically, we want to pick $r$ good enough to have some $\theta$ solved "easily", but cubic equation is not "easy", so we think "triple angle formula" to make it easier since we can't eliminate the linear term.

Comment: @Aayush yea you should ask another question about why the massive expression involving cosines and inverse cosines simplifies down.

Answer (score 0):

**I am deriving answer to this question in some other way**

We know $$ 8\cos\frac{\pi}{7}\cdot\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\cdot\cos\frac{4\pi}{7} = -1$$
By applying transformation formula

$$ 4\cos\frac{\pi}{7}\cdot2(\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\cdot\cos\frac{4\pi}{7}) = -1$$
$$ 4\cos\frac{\pi}{7}\cdot(\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}) = -1$$

$$ 4\cos\frac{\pi}{7}\cdot(-\cos\frac{\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}) = -1$$

$$ 4\cos\frac{\pi}{7}\cdot(-\cos\frac{\pi}{7}+2\cos^2\frac{\pi}{7}-1) = -1$$

**Putting $ \cos\frac{\pi}{7} = x $**

We will get the equation $$8x^3-4x^2-4x+1 =0 $$

*Similarly other angles like $\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}$ and $\cos\frac{3\pi}{7}$ may be derived in terms of cubic equations*